# A problem on successive differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=e^{\tan^{-1}x}=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n+\cdots$. Prove that $$(i)~~(1+x^2)y_{n+2}+(2(n+1)x-1)y_{n+1}+n(n+1)y_n=0$$
$$(ii)~~a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1}-na_n}{n+2}$$
$$(iii)~~e^{\tan^{-1}x}=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{6}x^3-\frac{7}{24} x^4+\cdots$$

I have solved 1st part by using Libnitz method. Please help me to solve the other two.

Answer (score 0):

$(ii):$ We have that:

$$y_{n}(0)=n!a_{n}$$

so,

$$y_{n}(0)=n!a_{n}\\
y_{n+1}(0)=(n+1)!a_{n+1}\\
y_{n+2}(0)=(n+2)!a_{n+2}$$

but, by $(i)$,

$$y_{n+2}(0)-y_{n+1}(0)+n(n+1)y_n(0)=0$$

then,

$$(n+2)!a_{n+2}-(n+1)!a_{n+1}+n(n+1)n!a_{n}=0\\
$$

and simplifying $(n+1)!$ we get:

$$a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1}-na_n}{n+2}$$

we also have that $a_0=y(0)=1$ and $a_1=y'(0)=1$.

Now solve the recurrence and find the general term to get $(iii)$.

Comment: thanks a lot. what about the last part?

Comment: @user1942348: you have to solve the recurrence and find the general term.

Comment: How you get this $a_1=a_0=1$

Comment: $a_0=y(0)=1$ and $a_1=y'(0)=1$

Comment: Ok. But how to get the general term of the recurrence?

Comment: Do you know how to solve recurrence?

Comment: no. it is new to me.

Comment: well, I think you should learn about that before move on. Try this one:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients